# Can a re.finditer() instance fail to match the original pattern?

Tags: python, regex

a. Is there a situation where the code below will cause an
    AssertionError?

b. If so, how do I prevent that?

```
def finditer_test(pattern, string, flags=0):
    for match_object in re.finditer(pattern, string, flags):
        assert re.match(pattern, match_object.group(0), flags)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can fail, for example when the pattern contains lookahead assertions.

Check `finditer_test(r'a(?=b)', 'abc')`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible - for example if the regex uses [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that look beyond the edges of the match itself:

```
(?<= )bar(?= )
```

will match `bar` in `"foo bar baz"`, but not in `"bar"` (which would be `group(0)`).